# Ошибка при выполнении программы: "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Tags: c++

Почему программа завершается на `S_object.findShortestWord(S_object.get(), str_value2);` с `Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 3.804 s`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class FirstClass {
    public:
        char* str_value;
    public:
        FirstClass(const char* value = ""):str_value(0) {
            set(value);
        }

        FirstClass(const FirstClass &obj):str_value(0) {
            set(obj.str_value);
        };

        ~FirstClass() {delete[] str_value;}

    void set(const char* value) {
        delete[] str_value;
        str_value = new char[strlen(value)+1];
        strcpy(str_value, value);
    }

    const char* get() const {
        return str_value;
    }
};

class SecondClass : public FirstClass {
    public:
        SecondClass(const char* str_value = "") : FirstClass (str_value) {}
    void findShortestWord(const char* in, char* out) {
        int len = strlen(in);

        int beginWord = 0;
        int lengthWord = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            while ( (in[i] == ' ') && ( in[i] != '\0')  ) i++;
            int begin = i;
            while ( (in[i] != ' ') && (in[i] != '\0') ) i++;
            int end = i;
            char tmp[256];
            for(int j = begin, k=0; j < end; j++, k++)
                tmp[k] = in[j];
            tmp[end - begin] = '\0';

            int currentLen = end - begin;
            if (currentLen < lengthWord) {
                lengthWord = currentLen;
                beginWord = begin;
            }
}

        for (int i = beginWord, k = 0; i < beginWord + lengthWord; i++, k++)
            out[k] = in[i];

        out[lengthWord] = '\0';
    }
};

int main() {
    char* str_value2;
    FirstClass F_object("Hello my world 1");

    printf("\nFirstClass init: %s", F_object.get());

    F_object.set("Hello my world 2");

    printf("\nFirstClass set: %s", F_object.get());

    FirstClass F_object2 = F_object;

    SecondClass S_object(F_object.get());

    printf("\nSecondClass init: %s", S_object.get());

    S_object.findShortestWord(S_object.get(), str_value2);

    //F_object = S_object;

    printf("\nSearch and delete: %s", str_value2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while ( (in[i] == ' ') && ( in[i] != '\0')  ) i++;` Второе условие можно убрать т.е. `while ( in[i] == ' ' ) i++;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно выделить память для `str_value2` Например `char str_value2[256]`. Или `char* str_value2 = new char[256]`.

```
char* str_value2 = new char[256];
//Еще какой то код
S_object.findShortestWord(S_object.get(), str_value2);
```

Comment: Как мне тогда работать с функцией?

Comment: Точно также, только нужно выделить память под второй параметр, потому что у вас он указывает на какую то случайную область памяти и при попытке записать туда что-нибудь программа падает

Comment: Я всё сделал. char* str_value2 = new char[256]; S_object.findShortestWord(S_object.get(), str_value2); но при выводе printf("\nSearch and delete: %s", str_value2[0]); получаю "null", почему так происходит?

Comment: при str_value2 ничего не получаю

Comment: У вас условие в функции `findShortestWord` неправильное должно быть `if ( (currentLen < lengthWord) || (lengthWord == 0) )`.

Answer (score 3):

Сразу же компилятор ругается - использована неинициализированная переменная `str_value2`!

Т.е. вы пишете куда-то, где это "куда-то" имеет совершенно случайный адрес... Что ж удивительного, что программа слетает?

Comment: Не при компиляции а при выполнении

Comment: @aaa Как для милиционера - медленно и два раза. *Ошибка при выполнении из-за неиницализированной переменной, о чем вас честно предупреждал компилятор, но вы наплевали на его предупреждение и решили выяснять причину здесь*. И еще раз: *Ошибка при выполнении из-за неиницализированной переменной, о чем вас честно предупреждал компилятор, но вы наплевали на его предупреждение и решили выяснять причину здесь*.